# how to keep the selected dropdown list value of form wizard in reactjs?

Tags: reactjs, drop-down-menu, formik

I have this multi level form wizard. When I clicking the next button and coming back to the previous stage, the selected dropdown list value has been reset. (sub category)

[image]

Sub Category field data populated from the Main Category selection.

Sub Category code:

```
<TextField
    select
    className={clsx('SelectMenu', styles.SelectMenu)}
    SelectProps={{ displayEmpty: true }}
    onChange={(e) => (
        setSubCategory(e.target.value),
        handleValChange("subCategory", e.target.value) //formik set value
    )}
>

<MenuItem value={"Select"} disabled>Select</MenuItem>
    {selectedMainCat[0] && selectedMainCat[0].subCategory.map((data, i) => (
        <MenuItem key={i} value={data.name}>{data.name.toUpperCase()}</MenuItem>
    ))}
</TextField>
```

Comment: I'm not seeing whole code but IMO you are not storing state parent element. When you change the component (click next button) previous component state reset. You can try to store the state parent component not in child component

Comment: @Neo I'm storing the state in useState hook. `const [subCategory, setSubCategory]: any = useState('');`

Answer (score 1):

Thanks @Neo. I fixed the issue by adding my state `const [subCategory, setSubCategory]: any = useState('');` as a prop to the rendering component.

```
<Features setSubCategory={setSubCategory} subCat={subCategory}/>

const Features = ({ setSubCategory, subCat }: Props) => {

   ....
   <MenuItem value={subCat} selected>{subCat}</MenuItem>
}
```